# Path Link sent to ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, response

1.I am trying to send my uploaded file path link by using response but it's sent like a string instead of hyperlink.
2. The code is below.

```
  string pathh = @"../../uploads";
  var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Uploads"];
    if (httpPostedFile != null)
    {
        var filename = httpPostedFile.FileName;
        var fileSavePath = 
        Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), filename);
        var retpath = fileSavePath;

        httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(pathh);
        newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, filename);

        Response.Write("<a href='newPath'>click here</a> ");
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but it's sent like a string instead of hyperlink"? Hyperlinks are strings. Could you please add an example how your response should look like and how it looks now?

Comment: Ok, got the problem. But "I cannot click" does not help to find the reason. I think first, we have to find out if your problem is on the server side or in JavaScript code. So, please open the network tools of your browser and check what you get as response. Post the exact result here and what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, filename);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("<a href="+newPath+">click here</a>");
            Response.End();  This is my code and the alert i get after ajax call is "<a href="upload/123.jpg">click here</a>"

Comment: Ok, let me guess… I think the problem is not on the server side but on the client side. If you use JavaScript alert() the reason is simply that these alerts do not render html. If "alert" is some kind of dhtml, your JavaScript seems to escape the html tags.

Comment: so  what should i do? if i send back a string it returns and says undefined. Ajax call does not go to a self created function even though i used web services and the method was static

Comment: Sorry, but with the given amount of information I can't help you. Please edit your answer and add your JavaScript code. too.